# Linq Parsing Error when trying to create seperation of concerns

Tags: linq, linq-to-nhibernate, fluent

I am in the middle of a refactoring cycle where I converted some extension methods that used to look like this:

```
   public static IQueryable<Family> FilterOnRoute(this IQueryable<Family> families, WicRoute route)
   {
        return families.Where(fam => fam.PODs
            .Any(pod => pod.Route.RouteID == route.RouteID));
    }
```

to a more fluent implementation like this:

```
public class SimplifiedFamilyLinqBuilder
{
    private IQueryable<Family> _families;

    public SimplifiedFamilyLinqBuilder Load(IQueryable<Family> families)
    {
        _families = families;
        return this;
    }

    public SimplifiedFamilyLinqBuilder OnRoute(WicRoute route)
    {
        _families = _families.Where(fam => fam.PODs
            .Any(pod => pod.Route.RouteID == route.RouteID));
        return this;
    }
    public IQueryable<Family> AsQueryable()
    {
        return _families;
    }
}
```

which I can call like this: (note this is using Linq-to-Nhibernate)

```
 var families =
            new SimplifiedFamilyLinqBuilder()
            .Load(session.Query<Family>())
            .OnRoute(new WicRoute() {RouteID = 1})
            .AsQueryable()
            .ToList();
```

this produces the following SQL which is fine with me at the moment: (of note is that the above Linq is being translated to a SQL Query)

```
select ... from "Family" family0_ 
where exists (select pods1_.PODID from "POD" pods1_ 
inner join Route wicroute2_ on pods1_.RouteID=wicroute2_.RouteID
where family0_.FamilyID=pods1_.FamilyID
and wicroute2_.RouteID=@p0);
@p0 = 1
```

my next effort in refactoring is to move the query part that deals with the child to another class like this:

```
public class SimplifiedPODLinqBuilder
{
    private IQueryable<POD> _pods;

    public SimplifiedPODLinqBuilder Load(IQueryable<POD> pods)
    {
        _pods = pods;
        return this;
    }

    public SimplifiedPODLinqBuilder OnRoute(WicRoute route)
    {
        _pods = _pods.Where(pod => pod.Route.RouteID == route.RouteID);
        return this;
    }
    public IQueryable<POD> AsQueryable()
    {
        return _pods;
    }
}
```

with SimplifiedFamilyLinqBuilder changing to this:

```
public SimplifiedFamilyLinqBuilder OnRoute(WicRoute route)
{
    _families = _families.Where(fam => 
        _podLinqBuilder.Load(fam.PODs.AsQueryable())
        .OnRoute(route)
        .AsQueryable()
        .Any()
    );
    return this;
}
```

only I now get this error:

> Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ParserException : Cannot parse expression 'value(Wic.DataTests.LinqBuilders.SimplifiedPODLinqBuilder)' as it has an unsupported type. Only query sources (that is, expressions that implement IEnumerable) and query operators can be parsed.

I started to implement IQueryable on SimplifiedPODLinqBuilder(as that seemed more logical than implementing IEnumberable) and thought I would be clever by doing this:

```
public class SimplifiedPODLinqBuilder : IQueryable
{
    private IQueryable<POD> _pods;

    ...

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _pods.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return _pods.Expression; }
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return _pods.ElementType; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return _pods.Provider; }
    }
}
```

only to get this exception (apparently Load is not being called and _pods is null):

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

is there a way for me to refactor this code out that will parse properly into an expression that will go to SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part `fam => _podLinqBuilder.Load(fam.PODs.AsQueryable()` is never going to work, because the linq provider will try to parse this into SQL and for that it needs mapped members of `Family` after the `=>`, or maybe a mapped user-defined function but I don't know if Linq-to-Nhibernate supports that (I never really worked with it, because I still doubt if it is production-ready).

So, what can you do?

To be honest, I like the extension methods much better. You switched to a stateful approach, which doesn't mix well with the stateless paradigm of linq. So you may consider to retrace your steps.

Another option: the expression in `.Any(pod => pod.Route.RouteID == route.RouteID));` could be paremeterized (`.Any(podExpression)`, with

```
OnRoute(WicRoute route, Expression<Func<POD,bool>> podExpression)
```

(pseudocode).

Hope this makes any sense.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply. 


I am hoping that there is a way to inform the provider how to handle this expression - but it appears that even if there is a way - it probably isn't worth the effort (after all - the extension method works quite well). 

I find that the extension method 'smells' - especially when the linq expressions they encapsulate are so core to my business logic, isn't this prime for following SOLID principles? It feels wrong to have this important code not be part of my IOC and not be classes I can extend or interfaces I can implement.

Comment: Another option I was thinking about before I went with the Fluent approach was to have the extension class simply depend on some strategy (provided by IOC)... 

`public static IQueryable<Family> FilterOnRoute(this IQueryable<Family> families, WicRoute route)
        {
            return _someStrategy.FilterOnRoute(families, route);
//OR            
return families.Where(_someStrategy.FilterOnRouteExpression);
        }` 

at the end of the day - it feels like a lot of work to pass around functions in a not so functional language

Comment: Business logic in stateless methods is perfectly OK to me. Strategy and IoC sounds good as well. Maybe that's our luxury problem with a multi-paradigm language like C#: too many options. One thing is often true though: stateless beats stateful.

Comment: as the language (and framework) matures - we certainly have  a lot of options

What is the expectation here - do I mark the question answered so that you get credit for your time - I don't feel like my question in answered (b/c) there has to be a way to make the expression parseable - but you are the only one to have replied and arguably the closest answer I will get.... do I mark it answered - I tried to at least give you a vote... but I am not 'priviledged' enough :(

Comment: That's up to you, no hard feelings :). You can wait a few days and see if someone else has a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate methods you *intend to call* from expressions you *intend to translate*.

This is great, you want each of those methods to run.  They return an instance that implements `IQueryable<Family>` and operate on that instance.

```
var families = new SimplifiedFamilyLinqBuilder()
  .Load(session.Query<Family>())
  .OnRoute(new WicRoute() {RouteID = 1})
  .AsQueryable()
  .ToList();
```

---

This is no good. you don't want Queryable.Where to get called, you want it to be an expression tree which can be translated to SQL.  But PodLinqBuilder.Load is a node in that expression tree which can't be translated to SQL!

```
families = _families
  .Where(fam => _podLinqBuilder.Load(fam.PODs.AsQueryable())
  .OnRoute(route)
  .AsQueryable()
  .Any();
```

You can't call .Load inside the Where expression (it won't translate to sql).

You can't call .Load outside the Where expression (you don't have the fam parameter).

---

In the name of "separation of concerns", you are mixing *query construction methods* with *query definition expressions*.  LINQ, by its Integrated nature, encourages you to attempt this thing which will not work.

---

Consider making *expression construction methods* instead of *query construction methods*.

```
public static Expression<Func<Pod, bool>> GetOnRouteExpr(WicRoute route)
{
  int routeId = route.RouteID;
  Expression<Func<Pod, bool>> result = pod => pod.Route.RouteID == route.RouteID;
  return  result;
}
```

called by:

```
Expression<Func<Pod, bool>> onRoute = GetOnRouteExpr(route);
families = _families.Where(fam => fam.PODs.Any(onRoute));
```

With this approach, the question is now - how do I fluidly hang my ornaments from the expression tree?

Comment: David thanks for the great response and thoroughness... I find myself on your last statement kind of where I started... how do I fluently do this... clearly its a rhetorical question - I am going to bang this around in my head some more and see if I can think of a way that is simple, intuitive, and reusable. This was a sort of experiment / proof of concept and I really like the intuitive and reusable output - sadly I am failing on simple.